# Typekit font Raleway not rendering properly on Windows

Tags: css, fonts, rendering, typekit

I was developing a website on a iMac and the character 'Š' was rendering properly, then I got some feedback that I missed the 'ˇ' symbol. I double checked it and I had spelled it correctly.

Does anyone know any 'CSS hack' or something to get the character rendered right?
I've tried text-shadow, anti-aliased font rendering without success.

Both examples were made on Google Chrome and font was imported from typekit using:

```
http://use.edgefonts.net/raleway:n1,n2,n3,n4,n5,n6,n7:all.js
```

Here's the code incase imgur and jsfiddle decide to drop the links:

```
* {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aYFw2/

[image: Rendering comparison between mac and windows]

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a problem with the font, when some font rendering techniques are used. You can see similar problems with characters like Å and É. Depending on font size, the diacritic marks may be cut off in part (e.g. so that just a small dot appears) or completely. E.g., in size 24px the problem does not exist.

The conclusion is that if you wish to such small font sizes, or want your text to be legible in small sizes, you should use a different font.